# Is there a function similar to Math.Max for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity framework query as follows;

```
From T In Db.MyTable
Where (T.Col1 - T.Col2) + T.Col3 - T.Col4 > 0 _
Select T
```

I now need to make sure that the bracketed part '(T.Col1 - T.Col2)' does not go below zero.

In .Net, I'd code it as follows (but obviously EF does not like Math.Max).

```
From T In Db.MyTable
Where Math.Max(T.Col1 - T.Col2,0) + T.Col3 - T.Col4 > 0 _
Select T
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I am using EF 2.0 (not the latest, just released version).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Max` isn't supported, but `Abs` is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx); will that do? Otherwise you'll have to use a ternary expression. In C#, I'd do:

```
from t in Db.MyTable
let m = t.Col1 >= t.Col2 ? t.Col1 - t.Col2 : 0
where m + t.Col3 - t.Col4 > 0
```

*However*, this will be inefficient at the DB level unless you have an expression index. So I'd suggest a computed column instead.

Comment: I reverted to bringing the database entities back into memory and using Math.Max on the object collection instead. Your answer works too, so thanks.